# Recipe fails with caret::train

Tags: r, r-caret, r-recipes

When using `caret` with `recipes` i get an error stating:

`Error in { : task 1 failed - "$ operator is invalid for atomic vectors"`

I managed to narrow it down to a problem with the recipe. But i am not sure what i'm doing wrong. Anyone has seen this before? The only relevant information i found was [here](https://github.com/topepo/caret/projects/1) and it stated:

> This happens when the model object fails and caused no recipe to be
>   available

Below follows the code i use. I cannot share the data, but the error appears when using mtcars as well.

```
library(caret)
library(tidymodels)
library(embed)
library(doParallel)

cluster <- makeCluster(detectCores() - 1) 
registerDoParallel(cluster)

df <- mtcars %>% 
  as_tibble() %>% 
  mutate(cyl = factor(cyl)) # to have one nominal variable

set.seed(123)
cv_split <- initial_split(df)
df_train <- training(cv_split)

set.seed(123)
cv_folds <- vfold_cv(df_train, v = 10, repeats = 10)

cv_ind <- rsample2caret(cv_folds)

rec <- 
  recipe(mpg ~ ., data = df_train) %>% 
  step_nzv(all_predictors()) %>% 
  step_lencode_mixed(all_nominal(), outcome = vars(mpg))

ctrl <- 
  trainControl(
    method = "repeatedcv",
    repeats = 10,
    index = cv_ind$index,
    indexOut = cv_ind$indexOut,
    allowParallel = TRUE)

train(rec,
    data = df_train,
    method = "glmnet",
    tuneLength = 20,
    trControl = ctrl)`
```

Comment: Without doParallel the code runs. The issue lies with the parallel part of of train / trainControl and glmnet and the recipe. You might be better off opening a ticket on the caret github page.

Comment: I get the same result as @phiver, also, if I call parallel and do recipe with step_lencode_mixed step, it works too.. So my guess is parallel clashes with step_lencode_mixed

Comment: You are both right. The problem is there for all the step_lencode_* steps. Github might be a better place to address this. Thanks!